Neovim and Pyright: limited auto-completion of Python code
Newbie to Neovim and Pyright. I learned from this tutorial: https://youtu.be/zHTeCSVAFNY?si=6G-b4caNl0Bx2xmG
As a result, I am happy to see this snippet auto-completing a for-loop:

But I am not seeing any auto-completion in other cases. Example 1: no auto-completion of the name of the variable "list" when writing for value in.... Example 2: although my python code includes import os at start of file, neovim does not suggest any os.walk auto-completion when writing  for root, dirs, files in os.w...:

I am wondering whether it is a limitation of my configuration or if it is a limitation of Pyright.
I would be grateful for your opinions and advices.
Infos about my sytem:

Linux Mint, release 6
Python 3.11
Neovim v0.10.2

As an answer to InSync's comment (4 nov 2024), I am adding now three lua plugin files (lsp-config.lua, none-ls.lua and completions.lua) for your information.
lsp-config.lua:
return {
    {
        "williamboman/mason.nvim", -- installation
        lazy = false,
        config = function()
            require("mason").setup() -- setup
        end,
    },
    {
        "williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim", -- installation
        lazy = false,
        opts = {
            auto_install = true, -- instead of something like ensure_installed = { "lua_ls", "pyright" },
        },
    },
    {
        "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
        lazy = false,
        config = function()
            local capabilities = require("cmp_nvim_lsp").default_capabilities()
            local lspconfig = require("lspconfig")
            lspconfig.html.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
            })
            lspconfig.lua_ls.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
            })
            lspconfig.pyright.setup({
                capabilities = capabilities,
            })

            vim.keymap.set("n", "K", vim.lsp.buf.hover, {})
            vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gd", vim.lsp.buf.definition, {})
            vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gr", vim.lsp.buf.references, {})
            vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>ca", vim.lsp.buf.code_action, {})
        end,
    },
}

none-ls.lua:
return {
    "nvimtools/none-ls.nvim", -- calls none-ls through short github url
    config = function()
        local null_ls = require("null-ls")
        null_ls.setup({
            sources = {
                null_ls.builtins.formatting.stylua, -- formatter for lua installed with Mason
                null_ls.builtins.formatting.black, -- formatter for python installed with Mason
                null_ls.builtins.formatting.isort, -- formatter for python installed with Mason
            },
        })
        vim.keymap.set("n", "<leader>gf", vim.lsp.buf.format, {}) -- for instance, adds double quotes instead of single quotes when the relevant language server advices it
    end,
}

completions.lua:
return {
    { "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp" },
    {
        "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip",
        dependencies = {
            "saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip",
            "rafamadriz/friendly-snippets",
        },
    },
    {
        "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
        config = function()
            local cmp = require("cmp")
            require("luasnip.loaders.from_vscode").lazy_load()

            cmp.setup({
                snippet = {
                    expand = function(args)
                        require("luasnip").lsp_expand(args.body) -- For `luasnip` users
                    end,
                },
                window = {
                    completion = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
                    documentation = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
                },
                mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
                    ["<C-b>"] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
                    ["<C-f>"] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
                    ["<C-Space>"] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
                    ["<C-e>"] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
                    ["<CR>"] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }),
                }),
                sources = cmp.config.sources({
                    -- { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
                    { name = "luasnip" }, -- For luasnip users.
                }, {
                    { name = "buffer" },
                }),
            })
        end,
    },
}


Please provide enough information for us to replicate the problem, including how you configure Pyright and such.

Thank you @InSync. For your information, I added in my post three lua configuration files. I hope it helps the understanding of my problem.

As far as I can tell, the suggested completions you are seeing have nothing to do with Pyright, they are snippets.

Input welcome @mkrieger1. It changes my perspective in the following way. It is not that Pyright does not do the full job. It is that Pyright does not do any job at all! What is wrong in my configuration?

Solution is: uncomment the line -- { name = 'nvim_lsp' }, in above file completions.lua. This way, Pyright is enabled to make auto-completion suggestions. Source: a comment beginning with "For anyone that..." below the video https://youtu.be/iXIwm4mCpuc?si=fBTLwIr3gUr__8-K
